# Cannot find Font T2A/cmr/m/n/9=larm0900, even in texlive-lang-cyrillic

Tags: fonts, babel, font-encodings, russian, betababel

I use babel with the russian option, and the error message is that

`Font T2A/cmr/m/n/9=larm0900 at 9.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.`

Firstly, I use tlmgr to search for this font, but there is no result. 
Then I download texlive-lang-cyrillic from [Macport](https://packages.macports.org/texlive-lang-cyrillic/), but I cannot find Font T2A/cmr/m/n/9=larm0900 in it.

If anyone has larm0900.tfm, please share it.

**Update**

As suggested by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) , I did `sudo tlmgr install collection-langcyrillic` and the tex file can be compiled, but the output is just a blank. This is because I used Xelatex, the output is normal when I use Pdflatex.

But is it possbile to use Xelatex and get the normal output?

Comment: Why not installing MacTeX? I have long removed MacPorts from my machines.

Comment: What I installed is BasicTex. If you have larm0900.tfm, could you share it?

Comment: You don't upgrade BasicTeX by installing MacPorts packages. If you need new packages over BasicTeX, you have to use TeX Live Utility.

Comment: By the way, sharing the TFM file is not sufficient; you need the whole font structure, which is much more than a single file.

Comment: Thanks, what should I do then rather than install the whole MacTex?

Comment: Launch TeX Live Utility, go to the “Packages” tab and install the `cyrillic` collection. But installing MacTeX is much easier.

Comment: By the way, is TeX Live Utility better than `tlmgr` in finding packages?

Comment: It's an interface to `tlmgr`.

Comment: If you use XeLaTeX on that example file, you would *not* receive a warning about a T2A encoded font. So the edit has nothing to do with your original question. The output with XeLaTeX is blank because the default font doesn't support Cyrillic. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Could you publish your comments as an answer and I'm going to accept it. By the way, is it possbile to use Xelatex and get the normal output?

Comment: Probably, also `cmsuper` should be installed to get Type 1 fonts instead of bitmap PK fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the font problem you need to install the `cyrillic` collection; however, you'll also need the `babel-russian` and the `hyphen-russian` TeX Live packages.

You can use `tlmgr` (as super user) or TeX Live Utility for install the missing packages. However, I recommend you to get rid of BasicTeX and to install the full MacTeX.

In order to run the example file (which appeared  in one version of your question) with XeLaTeX you need to use a font that supports Cyrillic, which the default Latin Modern doesn't.

Here we enter a mine field. The *full* MacTeX provides several OpenType fonts supporting Cyrillic, but you have BasicTeX, so probably none of them. You need to use `fontspec` and choose a font you have available among the system fonts. For instance, if you have PT Serif, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{PT Serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage*}{russian}
Интерференция света и теорема Белла
\end{otherlanguage*}
\end{document}
```